# Getting the error "Unexpected $end" in my class file

Tags: php, class, syntax-error

I'm writing a php library that handles different products, somewhere in my class I must have a missing curly brace or something but I can't find it.

Does someone with a debugger or keen eyes see anything wrong with this code?

http://pastie.org/953994

Thanks in advance!

Edit:  I think it's something with the query in the EquipmentDatabase class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ln 237, missing close quote...

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem!

Comment: glad to help :)
ever considered using an editor with nice syntax highlighting?

Comment: No never, classic notepad all the way :D

Answer (score 0):

Yep. There's a missing curly brace. Try inserting it either at the end (if you're defining the EquipmentDatabase inside of the Equipment class) or at the very end of the file before `?>` (if you're defining two separate classes.

Comment: I don't see where the missing curly brace is... I am defining two separate classes, each have closing braces.